# how can i align button bottom html css

Tags: html, css

How Can I fix my button is showing with reviews

I want to show my button after reviews stars

browser output screenshot:

[image]

I want something like that

[image]

how can I do that

I want my post my review button after reviews star, not like a row

Here is My Code:

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<form action="">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                                                <textarea placeholder="Enter Your Review Here..." cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control mt-3" required></textarea>
                                                <style>
                                                    .rating {
                                                        float: left;
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    .rating input {
                                                        display: none;
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    .rating label {
                                                        color: #ddd;
                                                        float: right;
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    .rating label:before {
                                                        margin: 5px;
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    .rating>input:checked~label,
                                                    .rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
                                                    .rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
                                                        color: #FFD700;
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    .rating-st {
                                                        font-size: 30px;
                                                        padding: 5px;
                                                    }
                                                </style>
                                                <div class="rating mt-3">
                                                    <input id="star_a-5" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="5" />
                                                    <label for="star_a-5" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                                                    <input id="star_a-4" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="4" />
                                                    <label for="star_a-4" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                                                    <input id="star_a-3" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="3" />
                                                    <label for="star_a-3" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                                                    <input id="star_a-2" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="2" />
                                                    <label for="star_a-2" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                                                    <input id="star_a-1" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="1" required/>
                                                    <label for="star_a-1" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post My Review">
                                            </form>
```

Comment: your code looks broken and doesn't really work. can you provide a full example?

Comment: Did you implement bootstrap into your code? If so can you provide us with the code?

Comment: @MrJ. I have edited my code can you please review it again

Comment: @MaZoli I have edited my code can you please review it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to do it is by adding break like so:

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<form action="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
    <textarea placeholder="Enter Your Review Here..." cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control mt-3" required></textarea>
    <style>
        .rating {
            float: left;
        }
        
        .rating input {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .rating label {
            color: #ddd;
            float: right;
        }
        
        .rating label:before {
            margin: 5px;
        }
        
        .rating>input:checked~label,
        .rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
        .rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
            color: #FFD700;
        }
        
        .rating-st {
            font-size: 30px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="rating mt-3">
        <input id="star_a-5" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="5" />
        <label for="star_a-5" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input id="star_a-4" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="4" />
        <label for="star_a-4" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input id="star_a-3" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="3" />
        <label for="star_a-3" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input id="star_a-2" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="2" />
        <label for="star_a-2" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input id="star_a-1" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="1" required/>
        <label for="star_a-1" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post My Review">
</form>
```

I highly recommend to check the other answers as they provide the proper and correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just removed unnecessary `float` property from star & rating div in styles and added a div wrapper on 'Post My Review' button to make it block.

Check this working example:

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<form action="">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
   <textarea placeholder="Enter Your Review Here..." cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control mt-3" required></textarea>
   <style>
      .rating input {
         display: none;
      }
      .rating label {
         color: #ddd;
      }
      .rating label:before {
         margin: 5px;
      }
      .rating>input:checked~label,
      .rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
      .rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
         color: #FFD700;
      }
      .rating-st {
         font-size: 30px;
         padding: 5px;
      }
   </style>
   <div class="rating mt-3">
      <input id="star_a-5" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="5" />
      <label for="star_a-5" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      <input id="star_a-4" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="4" />
      <label for="star_a-4" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      <input id="star_a-3" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="3" />
      <label for="star_a-3" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      <input id="star_a-2" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="2" />
      <label for="star_a-2" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      <input id="star_a-1" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="1" required/>
      <label for="star_a-1" class="full"><i class="fa fa-star rating-st" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
   </div>
   <div class="post-review mt-1">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post My Review" />
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, don't use *quick way by adding break* because it is buggy and poor code. If it works, thank your user-agent for the babysitting service

- **<br>** it is a self-closing tag, closing it is prohibited, is bad. Correct syntax is `<br> or <br/>` without self-invented closing-tag
- correct use of <br> - a very rare need to break line inside block of text. Very rare because there are plenty tools and solutions intended for this purpose. Using <br> means that you are fail. Using it between blocks is buggy

---

Problem with setting bellow caused (css) float: left;
I won't elaborate about float's side effects - its widely described and detailed in the Internet.

Since you are using tools like Bootstrap, you cannot reorganize the entire project. In other situations (own code) the strategy would be a cure, in your case all you get is a bandage:

Put `<hr class="break">` right in place where you need break line in your html
This line will be visible, if you don't like it add to css:

```
hr.break{ background: 0; border: 0; margin: 0;}
```

You can change class name, omit class - but it may affect every <hr> in your site. Change it's name for something spectacular will be a better choice.

---

Ironically, the *quick guy* got the solution but failed to implement it